# Eclipse is unable to find adb even when specified in Run Configurations

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, appium

I'm trying to run **Appium** tests with **Java** through **Eclipse**, but it can't find **ANDROID_HOME**. I've set the Run Configurations to use the ANDROID_HOME path and I've tried running Eclipse through terminal with `open /Applications/Eclipse.app`, but I'm still getting the error.

Worst part is this was all running fine yesterday, suddenly today Eclipse can't find the **SDK**. Running **ADB** in the terminal works fine as well. I changed nothing in the code

EDIT: I tried running a python test of Appium through terminal and got the same error. Restarted my machine and everything's working fine now lol. Not sure what the root cause is. This question can be closed

EDIT 2: It happened again, after around 30 minutes, started getting the error that it can't find adb. Is there a way to fix this? Right now it seems all I can do is restart my machine everytime it happens

Answer (score 0):

Received the same error when running a pyhton script through terminal, which means the error is not constrained to Eclipse. Restarted machine and everything's working fine now.